# StyleCop rules not enforced after updating to nuget package 1.0.0

Tags: c#, nuget, stylecop

After updating the StyleCop nuget package from StyleCop.Analyzers.1.0.0-rc3 (pre-release) to StyleCop.Analyzers.1.0.0 a few rules are no longer enforced. Namely rules: SA1208, SA1210, SA1600, SA1601.

With regards to rules **SA1208** and **SA1210**, CodeMaid *does* set up the usings correctly, but if turned off, no warnings are displayed.

The main problem however is **SA1600** and **SA1601**. I am aware that these rules does not enforce documentation on private members, but i no longer get warning on standard public members.

If I enable/disable other rules, I immediately see an effect, but neither of these rules gives me a warning like they used to.

---

*Edit: By enabling rule SA1652 on all projects, I now get warnings for **SA1600** and **SA1601**. I still don't have any using-warnings.*